# Row does not change color in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a macro in VBA that gets data from the "Input" sheet and populates the "Current" sheet. Everything has to be calibri 9 and columns J-M have to be all green, but row 133 for columns J-M is neither green nor size 9. I was wondering what I could do to fix this.

and this is currently the code that I have..

```
Sub Load16()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Define Workbooks
Dim loopCount As Integer
Dim loopEnd As Integer
Dim writeCol As Integer
Dim matchRow As Integer
Dim writeRow As Integer
Dim writeEnd As Integer

loopEnd = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Input").Range("A:A"))
writeEnd = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Input").Range("L:L"), "-1")
loopCount = 1
writeRow = 1

Worksheets("Buttons").Range("F17:I17").Copy
Worksheets("Current").Range("J2:M" & writeEnd).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Do While loopCount <= loopEnd

If Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, 12).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, 12).Value <> 0 Then

    Worksheets("Current").Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, 26).Value

    writeCol = 2
    Do While writeCol <= 9
        Worksheets("Current").Cells(writeRow, writeCol).Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, writeCol - 1)
        writeCol = writeCol + 1
    Loop

    writeCol = 14
    Do While writeCol <= 30
        Worksheets("Current").Cells(writeRow, writeCol).Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, writeCol - 5)
        writeCol = writeCol + 1
    Loop

    Worksheets("Current").Cells(writeRow, 31).Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(loopCount, 27)
    writeRow = writeRow + 1
    Else
End If

   loopCount = loopCount + 1
Loop

Worksheets("Current").Range("J1").Value = "Counsel"
Worksheets("Current").Range("K1").Value = "Background"
Worksheets("Current").Range("L1").Value = "Comments"
Worksheets("Current").Range("M1").Value = "BM Action"

Lookup Data for K - M and a few other things
loopCount = 2
Do While loopCount <= loopEnd

matchRow = 0
On Error Resume Next
matchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 1).Value, _
    Worksheets("Old").Range("A:A"), 0)
If matchRow = 0 Then
    Else
        Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 11).Value = Worksheets("Old").Cells(matchRow, 11).Value
        Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 12).Value = Worksheets("Old").Cells(matchRow, 12).Value
        Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 13).Value = Worksheets("Old").Cells(matchRow, 13).Value
End If

Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 10).Value =     Worksheets("Current").Cells(loopCount, 18).Value

loopCount = loopCount + 1
Loop

Sheets("Current").Range("A2:AE" & loopEnd).Sort Key1:=Sheets("Current").Range("H2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Worksheets("Current").Columns("A:BZ").AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Buttons").Select

MsgBox loopEnd - 1 & " Rows processed.  " & writeEnd & " Rows remain."

End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted which deals with setting font size or cell color, so it's unclear what you're really asking. Why would you *expect* to see 9pt green cells?

Comment: I suppose it might be that the OP is using `xlPasteAll` and over-ruling some existing formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set those cells to the format you want them to be, either manually (pasting data into them won't override the formatting) or through code like the below:

```
Range("J133:M133").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 9
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```